# Gitlab-runner on host with endpoint-device

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

I am wondering about one theoretical problem, i have several gitlab runners as Docker Containers on hosts to which endpoint device are connected via Ethernet cable.

I would like the endpoint device to be turned on only when Gitlab calls a specific Gitlab-runner (the endpoint device is controlled separately) and turned off as soon as the job is completed and the given gitlab-runner is temporarily unemployed.

I don’t know how to approach this problem yet, any suggestions?

Gitlab Server - 16.0.3-CE
Gitlab-runner - 16.0.1

Thanks for all ideas

Comment: How is the device turned on and off?

Comment: By the Power Distribution Units (ssh connection into PDU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you might be able to implement this.

1. Implementing required steps in your runner configuration
2. Using a [custom runner executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/custom.html)
3. Using script steps in your GitLab jobs

#### Using runner configuration

The [runner configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) has two key configuration parameters: `pre_build_script` and `post_build_script` which can be used to run scripts before and after a job runs. You could configure your `pre_build_script` to turn on your device and configure your `post_build_script` to turn the device off.

These can be set in the runner `config.toml`:

```ini
[[runners]]
# ...
pre_build_script = /usr/local/bin/turn-on-device
post_build_script = /usr/local/bin/turn-off-device
```

Caveat: this assumes your runner is configured to only allow one job at a time (the `concurrent` setting is set to `1`). Otherwise, if you plan to have concurrent jobs access the device simultaneously, you will need your `pre_build` and `post_build` scripts to make a determination of whether the device is already on or in use by another job to ensure that your `post_build` script does not turn off the device while another job is using the device.

### Using a custom runner

Similar to the above, [custom executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/custom.html) can define a `prepare_exec` program to run to prepare the job environment and a `cleanup_exec` program to cleanup the job environment after the job, which you can configure to execute scripts used to turn your device on and off.

This might be a useful approach if you're already using a custom executor for some other reason.

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = "custom"
  executor = "custom"
  # ...
  [runners.custom]
    # ...
    prepare_exec = "/usr/local/bin/turn-on-device"
    # ...
    cleanup_exec = "/usr/local/bin/turn-off-device"
    # ...
```

### Using script steps in your GitLab job

Yet another approach would be to implement something similar to the approaches described above, but using `before_script:` and `after_script:` steps to turn the device on and off as part of the job itself.

```yaml
before_script:
  - ./turn-device-on.sh # or whatever

after_script:
  - ./turn-device-off.sh # or whatever
```

This approach would work well with cases where you do not control the runner configuration.

Caveat: in some cases, `after_script:` may not run, such as in the case of a runner system failure, or [if a job is canecelled](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4843)